# Get value from selected option and pass it to the function

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, razor

Hi im making a reservation page in razor pages asp.net. On my page I have two drop downlist. One for the location other for the rooms of that specific location. I want to pass the value of that selected location to the function which shows the rooms (function is named showRoom()), so that the rooms will be shown depending on which location you selected. How do i do that with html? I tried something but didnt really work. Here is the html code

```
<td>Select location</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="locations" name="Location">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.PopulateReservations())
                                            {                                        
                                                <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.LocationName)</option>
                                                
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>
                                <td>Select Room</td>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <select id="rooms" name="Room">
                                            @foreach(var reservations in @Model.ShowRoom(string LocationName))
                                            {
                                               <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>
                                                 
                                            }
                                        </select>                                       
                                    </div>
```

Here is the function showRoom

```
public List<WorkspaceModel> ShowRoom(string loc)
        {
            var cs = Database.Database.Connector();
            List<WorkspaceModel> res = new List<WorkspaceModel>();
            using var con = new NpgsqlConnection(cs);
            {
                string query = "Select room FROM workspaces WHERE location = '"+ loc +"'";
                using NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, con);
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    using (NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            res.Add(new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = dr["room"].ToString() });
                        }
                    }
                    
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This pattern is called "cascading dropdowns", you can read plenty of examples etc online if you search for that. Essentially it's usually done by using javascript to handle the "change" event of the first dropdown, which then sends an AJAX request to the server containing the ID of the selected item, and the server returns the valid options to put into the second dropdown, based on that ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is  a demo(I use fake data to test):

class:

```
public class PopulateReservation
    {
        public string LocationName { get; set; }

    }
    public class WorkspaceModel
    {
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
    }
```

TestDropDown.cshtml:

```
<td>Select location</td>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="locations" name="Location">
        @foreach (var reservations in @Model.PopulateReservations)
        {
            <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.LocationName)</option>

        }
    </select>
</div>
<td>Select Room</td>
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="rooms" name="Room">
        @foreach (var reservations in @Model.Rooms)
        {
            <option>@Html.DisplayFor(m => reservations.RoomName)</option>

        }
    </select>
</div>

<form>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>
@section scripts{ 
    <script>
        $('#locations').on('change', function () {
            var arr = [];
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=ShowRoom',
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            data: { "loc": $("#locations").val() },
            dataType:"json"
        }).done(function (data) {
            $("#rooms").empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                $("#rooms").append('<option> ' + item["roomName"] + ' </option>');
            });
           
        });
    });
    </script>
}
```

TestDropDown.cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestDropDownModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public List<PopulateReservation> PopulateReservations { get; set; }
        [BindProperty]
        public List<WorkspaceModel> Rooms { get; set; }
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            PopulateReservations = new List<PopulateReservation> {
                new PopulateReservation { LocationName = "location1" },
                new PopulateReservation { LocationName = "location2" },
                new PopulateReservation { LocationName = "location3" }
            };
            Rooms = new List<WorkspaceModel> {
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "Room1" },
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "Room2" },
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = "Room3" },
            };
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPost()
        {
            
            return Page();
        }
        public IActionResult OnPostShowRoom(string loc)
        {
            List<WorkspaceModel> l= new List<WorkspaceModel> {
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = loc + "Room1" },
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = loc + "Room2" },
                new WorkspaceModel { RoomName = loc + "Room3" },
            };
            return new JsonResult(l);

        }
    }
```

result:
[image]